# Is it phrase or clause?

Tags: grammar

Look the below sentence please:

> To be honest, I didn't do anything

Here, is "To be honest" a phrase? If it is a phrase, then what kind of phrase it is? I know phrase does not have subject verb combination and "To be honest" has no subject verb combination.

Comment: *To be honest* is both a dependent clause and a phrase.

Comment: It can only be a clause (infinitival) since it has a subject-predicate structure, though the subject is covert, as in most non-finite clauses, but understood as "me". The predicate is "to be honest" and the verb is "be". Phrases don't have a subject-predicate structure.

Answer (score 1):

"To be honest" is an infinitive clause. Infinitive clauses sometimes omit the subject, or have the subject implied. Here the subject is omitted, and the verb is "to be".

It is also a phrase. Most clauses are also phrases.